# NGINX: dispatch a request to multiple endpoints

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

For a test environment, I need to dispatch a single request to multiple endpoints (i.e I have to duplicate the request).
I would like to do so using only NGINX, but I am not sure that it is possible.

For my host, my configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    server_name myserver.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.com;

    ssl_certificate      ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  ssl/key.pem;

    proxy_set_header        Host myserver.com;
    proxy_ssl_name          myserver.com;
    proxy_ssl_server_name   on;

    location  / {
                proxy_pass https://server1/;
            }
```

I tried to use multiple proxy_pass tags, like this:

```
location  / {
                    proxy_pass https://server1/;
                    proxy_pass https://server2/;
                    proxy_pass https://server3/;
                }
```

Of course I did not really expected it to work, but I think that it will help you to understand what I am trying to achieve.

So my question is: is it possible to achieve this with NGINX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called HTTP shadowing. Nginx might not allow it, but [GoReplay](https://github.com/buger/goreplay) does.

Comment: Not really what I expected, but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 4):

Too late, but this is what you were looking for:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).